# No devel block is defined for automake? Error when using Homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, error

I'm getting an odd error that google seems to only have a handful of (unhelpful) results for.

When I use homebrew to try and install some dev libraries or tools, it's coming up:

```
brew install -v --devel --fresh  automake autoconf libtool wget libimobiledevice
**Error: No devel block is defined for automake**
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because libmobiledevice is no longer on --devel branch, remove that and you should be all set.

`brew install -v --fresh libimobiledevice`